# Make an image move across the screen at the correct speed for all displays

Tags: java

I have a top down shooter using the paint method and I would like for it to work on all displays. It works by getting the resolution and dividing the x and y by 40 to separate it all up into squares.
My method of making the bullets move is by having a thread and a move method.

```
public void move(){
x += dx;
y += dy;
}
```

But if the persons computer is smaller, the bullet would move across the screen quicker. How can I get it to move at slower on smaller screens and faster on bigger screens? 
Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Your wording is confusing.  Do you want all bullets to cross the screens in the same amount of time, or the bullets to have the same velocity (in pixels/second)?

Comment: I want the bullets to take the same amount of time to cross the screen.

Answer (score 0):

What do you actually mean by slower? Do you mean as in the total time (measured in seconds) for the bullet to move across the screen is different in different devices?

Assuming that you did all calculation correctly as you described, I think you forgot one factor: different devices have different computing speed (and may be screen update speed also), so a "tick" in one device might be longer or shorted than some other. So when you call move, you should calculate how much time has passed from that last time moved() was called, and then you would calculate dx and dy based on it. Hope this make sense

Comment: If I have a bigger screen and use my move method, it would take longer for the bullet to travel from one side of the screen to the other then if I had a smaller screen. Because a smaller screen would have less pixels so it would be quicker. I want the bullet to take the same amount of time to travel from one side of the screen to the other on all sizes of screen. Hope that helps.

Comment: It looks like the difference of the screen size should be taken cared of when you get the screen resolution and divide it by 40. What was not taken into account of is the time move() is called. In a faster device move() might be called 60 times per second while in a slower device it might be called 30 times per second.

Comment: I have made it so that it should work at the same frame rate on all computers by making it update after a set amount of time. So I calculate the time passed like you mentioned earlier.

Comment: In theory it should have worked then. I guess the problem then is somewhere in the code. Perhaps you should post more code and someone can review it for you. As a tip for debugging - your bullet should take exactly 40 frames to move across the screen. May be you should check at frame 40 to see where your bullet is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're forgetting not every computer runs at the same speed, if you've got this looping as fast as it can it will run very different on every computer. I suggest implementing delta scaling, this consists of timing the last frame, say you want 60fps, that means it needs to be 16 milliseconds, so take the time and divide it such as:

```
int lastframe = getFrameTime();
float scaler = lastFrame/(1000f/targetFrameRate)
```

then multiply all movements to this scale. such as:

```
public void move() {
    x += dx * scaler;
    y += dy * scaler;
}
```

A also see what you mean with different screen sizes being faster, this is because of the pixel density, to get this you will have to get the screen physical dimensions along with the resolution. For example if your screen is 20mm wide and its 1280x720, it's 20/1280 , this gives you the fact that each pixel is 0.015mm wide. You can then use the above scalar technique to scale them to move a physical world speed.